# ListView layout not showing elements

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Hello dear Stackoverflow community. I'm coming to you for help, as you can guess.

I have a ListView for which each row should follow this layout, `row_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:background="@color/brownish">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/passport_flag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/country_flag" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/exp_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="16dip"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/exp_date"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/birth_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="16dip"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/birth_date"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_above="@+id/exp_date"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/exp_date" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/document_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/exp_date"
    android:layout_above="@id/birth_date"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:text="@string/document_number"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I implemented a custom `ArrayAdapter`, for which here is the code:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<EPassport> {

    public static final String TAG = "CustomArrayAdapter";
    private final String DOCUMENT_NUMBER = "Passport number: ";
    private final String DATE_OF_BIRTH = "Date of birth: ";
    private final String DATE_OF_EXPIRY = "Date of expiry: ";

    private Context context;
    private List<EPassport> ePassportsList;

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView documentNumber;
        public TextView birthDate;
        public TextView expDate;
        public ImageView flag;
    }


    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, List<EPassport> ePassportsList) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_layout, ePassportsList);
        this.context = context;
        this.ePassportsList = ePassportsList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater =
                    (LayoutInflater) context
                            .getApplicationContext()
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);

            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.documentNumber = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.document_number);
            viewHolder.birthDate = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.birth_date);
            viewHolder.expDate = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.exp_date);
            viewHolder.flag = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.passport_flag);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }


        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        EPassport rowPassport = this.ePassportsList.get(position);

        holder.expDate.setText(DATE_OF_EXPIRY + rowPassport.getDateOfExpiry());
        holder.birthDate.setText(DATE_OF_BIRTH + rowPassport.getDateOfBirth());
        holder.documentNumber.setText(DOCUMENT_NUMBER + rowPassport.getDocumentNumber());
        if (rowPassport.getCountryCode() != null) {
            String alpha2CountryCode = null;
            try {
                alpha2CountryCode = ISO3166Database.getAlpha2Code(rowPassport.getCountryCode());
            } catch (IllegalCountryCodeException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            holder.flag.setImageResource(
                    getContext()
                    .getResources()
                    .getIdentifier(alpha2CountryCode, "drawable", getContext().getPackageName()));
        }

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

I work with Android Studio 1.4 and the 'Design' tab of my `row_layout.xml` looks exactly how I want it to be.

When I run the application however, of the three text fields only one shows up on the screen.

I can't figure out the why. If anyone would like to give me a hand with this one, it would be greatly appreciated.

Image of the row layout as rendered by android studio:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Image as shown on the screen:

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this as row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FF664747"
android:padding="8dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/documentNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Document number: " />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/birthDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/documentNumber"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:text="Birth date: " />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/expireDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/birthDate"
    android:text="Expire date: " />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/passportFlag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/documentNumber"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Just change your data and color.